# Proving this linear congruence with prime number modulo

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck by proving this lemma. My idea is to use the Chinese Remainders Theorem. But how to start?

We have $n,p,q\in \mathbb N$

$p$ and $q$ are prime numbers with $p \neq q$

This the statement which is obviously true. But how do I start?

$x \equiv n \ (mod \ p \cdot q) \iff x\equiv n\pmod p$ and $x\equiv n\pmod q$

Due to this logical equivalence I have to prove in two ways "$\Rightarrow$" and "$\Leftarrow$"

One approach for "$\Rightarrow$" would be something like $x=n + k \cdot p\cdot q$ where $k$ is a multiple.

For "$\Leftarrow$" I would go for the Chinese Remainders Theorem.

Comment: Both ideas are correct. What is the question?

Comment: how to start the proof

Answer (score 1):

In the forward direction, you've basically got it. You're written a statement that expresses what you're given; now write down something that expresses what you need to show, and you'll pretty much be done.

In the reverse direction, you don't really need CRT. You have that $p|x-n$, and $q|x-n$. Can you see why this is enough to show that $pq|x-n$?

Comment: I tried my best figuring out how to come $x=n+k\cdot p$ and $x=n+k\cdot q$ to $x=n+k\cdot p \cdot q$ but I don't know how.

Comment: Keep the $n$ subtracted on the other side with the $x$. Then you have $x-n=pk$, and $q$ divides that quantity. Since $q$ doesn't divide $p$, it must divide $k$. Does that help?